# Ploting a skewed normal distribution in R

Tags: r, math, plot

How can I plot a skewed normal distribution in R, given the number of cases, the mean, standard deviation, median and the [MAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation).

A example would be that I have 1'196 cases, were the mean cost is 6'389, the standard deviation 5'158, the median 4'930 and the MAD 1'366. And we know that the billed case always cost something, so the cost must always be positive.

The best answer to this problem I could find is from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17995/54064 and recommends the usage of the [sn](http://cran.r-project.org/package=sn) package. However I could not figure out how to use it for my concrete use case.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success with `fGarch` package.

```
require("fGarch")
hist(rsnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1, xi = 15))

mmm <- replicate(300, {
  x <- rsnorm(1196, mean = 6389, sd = 5158, xi = 15)
  c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
})

> mean(mmm[1, ])
[1] 6404.312
> mean(mmm[2, ])
[1] 5169.572
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! The manual says "xi" is the skewness parameter. How to find it's size? How did you come up with 15?

Comment: And the price is always positive. So the distribution might probably be not normal. How can I reflect this?

Comment: @leo I tried 1.5 and then 15. Presto. If you want to simulate other skewed distributions, you'll probably need another tool.