# Random Numbers in R

Tags: r, simulation

I want to generate random numbers in R . The mean, standard deviation, and the median are given.
Mean: 145
SD: 15
Median: 150
Any fitted distribution would work. I'm just concerned with how to go about it.
Also, is it possible to simulate a skewed normal distribution?

Comment: This is not possible.  If the numbers are normally distributed,  the mean will equal the median. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I edited it. The the question still stands though, either uniform or any other valid distribution.

Comment: @G5W can you explain why? I'm sorry it might sound stupid but I'm an undergrad student and I'm not that deep into statistics

Comment: The uniform distribution also has mean == median, see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)).

Comment: @RuiBarradas alright I edited it again. Please bear with me I'm new to statistics....

Comment: @G5W how about a skewed distribution?

Comment: Yes.  You need a skewed distribution to get this.

Comment: @G5W how do I do it in R?

Comment: So you have two questions- one a programming question and one is not. The first question is what distribution has these properties? That is not a programming question and you might do better asking that on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  Once you know what you want to implement,  you can ask the question of how to implement it in R here.

Comment: @G5W let's go with skewed normal distribution. Is there a method in R that incorporates the statistics above to produce a simulation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ploting a skewed normal distribution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798938/ploting-a-skewed-normal-distribution-in-r)

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856676/8245406) with Python code. It doesn't answer the issue of known SD, though.

Comment: Try `library(fGarch)`; `x <- rsnorm(1000, mean = 145, sd = 15, xi = -50)`. You might have to tweak the parameters a bit, especially `xi` but this is close.

Comment: @dcarlson how did you calculate xi?

Comment: Trial and error to get close to the desired median.